# Google Geocoder client side limit - per IP or per API_KEY?

Tags: google-maps

I am using client-side google maps geocoding, but loading the maps API JavaScript using API_KEY. Do you know if the limit of 2500 requests is per IP address or per API-KEY in this case. And do you think I can remove the API_KEY in order to use the limit of 2500 per IP address?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daily limit goes per API_KEY, there is request per second limit that goes per IP. You should be able to see limits in administrative console, where you choose to enable different APIs.

Comment: Thank you. This means that for client side geocoding it is more logical to not use the API_KEY at all as specified in this article: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

Comment: @LyubenIvanov Absolutelly.